# get value display in spinner

Tags: android, spinner, display

How can i display selected item in spinner A show in spinner B..?

```
 <string-array name="type_report">
    <item>Emergency</item>
    <item>Sponsor</item>
    <item>House</item>
</string-array>
```

Both of spinner used same "type_report" ..spinner A and B will show Emergency in first position. My question is when i choose "House" in spinner A in activity home , then spinner B in other activity will show "House" in first position ..

**spinner A list**

```
   <item>Emergency</item>     
   <item>Sponsor</item>       
   <item>House</item>
```

after choose "**House**"
**spinner B list will show**

```
<item>House</item>
<item>Emergency</item>
<item>Sponsor</item>
```

Comment: use setselected method, for example if house is selected in first activity then find the position and pass it to second activity and use setselected(position) method the set default spinner item

Comment: use `setOnItemSelectedListener` on spinner A and change B when A is changed

Comment: How can i find the position in first activity then pass into other activity ?

Answer (score 1):

```
spinnerA.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    /**
     * Called when a new item is selected (in the Spinner)
     */
     public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, 
                int pos, long id) {
       Intent intent=new Intent(this,SecondaActivity.class);
       intent.putExtra("index",pos);
       startActivity(intent);


      }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            // Do nothing, just another required interface callback
        }

});
```

Now in your secondActivity you have to place the selected index's item on first position like this

```
Intent mIntent = getIntent();
int pos= mIntent.getIntExtra("index", 0);
String valueAtIndex = yourArray[pos];
  for(int i = pos; i > 0; i--){
  yourArray[i] = yourArray[i-1];
  }
  yourArray[0] = valueAtIndex;
 //now set this array to second Spinner
  ArrayAdapter spinnerBArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
  android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
    yourArray);
  spinnerB.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
```

Tested and working code

Comment: Actually after i select item in spinner A , i putExtra to other activity which contain spinner B , So i want display item that i choose in first position in spinner B

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean 'yourArray' .. ? That string-array "type_report" ?

Comment: I get wrong at yourArray even it change to type_report .. Actually how to initialize 'yourArray' .. ? cannot resolve symbol 'yourArray' ..

Comment: you can get your array from resources like `private String[] type_report;` and  later initialize  `type_report= getResources().getStringArray(R.array.type_report)`;

Comment: Thanks a lot Sir .. It worked .. You saved my day .. :-) ..One more question, if i change value at spinner B , how can i get new value.

newreport = reports.getSelectedItem().toString(); 

It still hold value 'House' that we choose at spinner A even we already update in spinner B ..